# IBM-Watson Asynchronous requests fail

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

i am implementing Watson Assistant v2 asynchronous request (with no thread, as it is not required). but i end up with crash for making network call on main thread. which means this call is not called asynchronous on android.

"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" - This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread

code:-

```
  public void sendMessage(String message){
        Log.d("TAG","message :"+message+", session id:"+sessionId);
        MessageInput input = new MessageInput.Builder()
                .messageType("text")
                .text(message)
                .build();
        MessageOptions options = new MessageOptions.Builder(assistanID, sessionId)
                .input(input)
                .build();
        assistant.message(options).enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                GsonWatson gsonparse = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), GsonWatson.class);
                mainActivity.messageRecievedFromAssistant(gsonparse.getOutput().getGeneric().get(0).getText());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }





 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.callIamApi(IamTokenManager.java:187)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.requestToken(IamTokenManager.java:108)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.getToken(IamTokenManager.java:78)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.setAuthentication(WatsonService.java:375)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.createCall(WatsonService.java:206)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.createServiceCall(WatsonService.java:240)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.Assistant.message(Assistant.java:151)
        at com.XXX.IBMwatson.sendMessage(IBMwatson.java:78)
        at com.XXX.ibmwatson.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

- did some digging in source code of Watson service. one of call which is made in background is run on main thread

> class:
>   XXX\files-2.1\com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud\core\6.13.2\673b89ba561c095131da91c327c99800f12b6d9f\core-6.13.2-sources.jar!\com\ibm\watson\developer_cloud\service\security\IamTokenManager.java

method: callIamApi:187

> line:187:- okhttp3.Response response = call.execute();

this call is made on main thread.

Comment: What is your code? Are you using this SDK? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/assistant The stack shows Assistant API V1 is in use

Comment: `compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:6.13.2'` .

Comment: you need to add the code in order for us to see what the problem is

Comment: @GermanAttanasio please look at it now

Comment: @JolsonDaCosta I was able to recreate the issue so thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'm going to make an issue for it in the Java SDK repo to track and I'll post a link here for you to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a bug in the Java SDK where, as you pointed out, the call to authenticate through IAM is still made on the main thread. This bug is currently documented [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/1041).

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can explicitly wrap the call in a new thread. One way to do this is with an `AsyncTask`. Below is an example:

```java
private class MessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    MessageInput input = new MessageInput.Builder()
      .messageType("text")
      .text(params[0])
      .build();
    MessageOptions options = new MessageOptions.Builder(assistantId, sessionId)
      .input(input)
      .build();
    assistant.message(options).enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
        Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
      }
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Exception e) {}
    });
    return "sent message successfully";
  }
}
```

where you just call it like this:

```java
new MessageTask().execute("This is an example message");
```